# Criar Json por PHP baseado no Mysql

Tags: php, json

Gostaria de saber se alguém encontra algum erro em meu código pois estou à tentar criar um Json com o PHP porem ele só retorna `NULL`.

> Meu servidor Host utiliza PHP 5.6

```
 <?PHP    
    $host = "...";    
    $usuario = "...";    
    $senha = "...";    
    $banco = "...";    

    $database = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$senha,$banco);    

$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbconsultas");

$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $response[$i]['url']  = $row['url']; 
  $response[$i]['title']= $row['title'];
  $data['posts'][$i] = $response[$i];
  $i=$i+1;
} 

$json_string = json_encode($data);

$file = 'file.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
?>
```

Comment: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: @MarceloBoni eu tentei utilizar o 'mysqli' porem criou o Null do mesmo jeito

Comment: Nunca utilize a extensão mysql, a extensão esta obsoleta e não funciona mais a partir do php 7

Comment: estou usando o php 5.6 no meu servidor @MarceloBoni

Comment: coloca no inicio do seu código `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ai verifica se deu alguma mensagem e posta aqui pra ajudar.

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, troque a extensão pra `mysqli` ;] Não é porque seu servidor ainda suporta a extensão, que ela ainda deve ser usada

Comment: Alterei para o `mysqli` porem não tive exito na criação do Json @MarceloBoni

Comment: O que retorna `null`?  Execute um `var_dump( json_last_error_msg());` e verifique se existe algum erro (e qual é ele) no json_encode. Veja seo o banco de dados está em UTF8 também.

Comment: @Inkeliz o `null` é o Json que recebo após criar ele com o php. e o `var_dump` devo colocar aonde mesmo ?

Comment: Coloque no fim do código. O `json_last_error_msg()` vai retornar o código do último erro que ocorreu no `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Inkeliz `string(8) "No error"` esse foi o erro que recebi

Comment: @MatheusRohwedder, você colocou o `json_last_error()` após a chamada do `json_encode()`? Isso pode ser algo com UTF8 já que está pegando URLs e títulos.

Comment: @FernandoBagno sim foi apos o `json_encode()` terei de dar uma olhada mas acho que esta em utf-8 sim

Comment: Seria legal ver essa sua base o que tem, pois seu código rodou aqui pra mim tranquilamente usando uma base minha.

Comment: @FernandoBagno pelo que vi meu phpmyadmin esta usando utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: @FernandoBagno não sei o que aconteceu porém misteriosamente funcionou

Comment: Você mudou o encode? Tá usando UTF8? O ideal é que seu banco esteja em UTF8_general_c

Comment: @FernandoBagno eu implementei o codigo do Anderson abaixo e funcionou agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho o PHP inferior ao 7 na minha máquina, então não consigo testar seu código para lhe afirmar pontualmente qual é o erro, mas utilizando o MySQLi é possível fazer algo como:

```
// Conecta com o banco de dados:
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sopt");

// Seleciona todos os registros da tabela:
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tbconsultas");

// Retorna todos os registros:
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Escreve o resultado JSON em arquivo:
file_put_contents("file.json", json_encode($data));
```

---

Caso não seja possível a utilização da função `mysqli_fetch_all` como apresentado acima, basta fazer um laço de repetição iterando sobre todos os registros e armazenando em um *array*.

```
// Lista que armazenará todos os registros:
$rows = [];

// Percorre todos os registros:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // Adiciona o registro na lista:
    array_push($rows, $row);

}
```

No final, basta converter a lista para JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Anderson, tentei utilizar as funções `mysqli` que mostrou acima porem não obtive exito

Comment: @MatheusRohwedder então provavelmente o erro não está nas chamadas do MySQL, mas sim no seu laço de repetição que está muito confuso. Eu testei o código acima e funciona perfeitamente. Você não precisa do laço, basta utilizar a função `mysqli_fetch_all`.

Comment: Ao tentar utilizar o mysqli_fetch_all não consigo nem rodar o arquivo pelo navegador

Comment: @MatheusRohwedder Por quê não? Qual é o erro que aparece? Por favor, dê detalhes! Consegue postar seu código no http://ideone.com e mandar o link? Quantos registros há na tabela? Está dando *timeout*?

Comment: O codigo que estou usando é o que foi postado na pergunta, eu coloquei o seu codigo no lugar do meu, apenas colocando minha conexão com o db, ha 1 linha de registros na tabela para teste, porem tem 8 colunas.

Comment: erro ao usar o seu cod `meusite.com.br não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Se o código está igual ao meu, deveria funcionar. Por favor, poste seu código no Ideone e mande o link. Provavelmente você fez algo errado e não está percebendo. Por exemplo, na função `mysqli_query` você passou o parâmetro da conexão?

Comment: http://ideone.com/1HC8wQ com o seu código

Comment: Para usar o `mysqli_fetch_all` precisa do mysqlnd.

Comment: mas ai para usar o `mysqlnd` ia ter de mudar muitas coisas? @Inkeliz